What optimizations does the Rust compiler actually make for opt-level > 0?
One of my tests takes ~5.5s to complete for a Rust program I'm writing. However, if I run the test with a profile that sets opt-level to 1, 2, or 3, it takes ~250ms.
My program is fairly straightforward but is pretty CPU-intensive with lots of bitwise arithmetic and function calls, does no I/O, is not very memory-hungry, and is single-threaded. The test is entirely deterministic.
I suspect this is largely due to function inlining (for example, one function is called 1.5 million times throughout the test and gets inlined when using compiler optimization), but I don't have a frame of reference for how much overhead that really saves. Are there other things that could cause such a massive speedup? Taking advantage of CPU architecture, etc.?

The same sort of stuff other LLVM-based compilers do at various optimization levels? This is a ridiculously broad question, the specifics are going to vary from release to release.

To my knowledge Rust doesn't have its own optimizer, so the question is basically "what does the LLVM optimizer do," which, when put in list form, would be gigantic and not at all appropriate as an SO answer. Basically, the answer is "lots of things." Inlining, constant folding, loop unrolling, dead code elimination, reordering instructions, caching of common subexpressions, elimination of provably-useless bounds checks, and so on. In release mode, Rust also omits arithmetic overflow/underflow checks.

@cdhowie: Rust does perform some MIR optimisations before codegen.

Yes, my question was in part informed by https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/optimizations.html
